# How can I properly terminate an unused gate driver channel?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, nmos, gate-driving

I have a circuit where I need only one MOSFET to be controlled but I have a dual channel gate driver capable of driving both high and low side MOSFET. I only need the low side channel for the application. As for now going with single channel gate driver is not an option. My question is how can I terminate the unused high side channel pins of the gate driver? Or should I leave the pins unconnected?
Gate driver is: LF2106N[image]

Comment: Just leave it open?

Comment: @winny yes, should I leave it open?